# Tool-tip in line-chart of composite chart not working in dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am plotting a composite chart in dc which contains one bar and one line chart. The code used is given below. However, the tool-tips for bar charts are coming out fine but the tool-tips for line chart don't show up at all.There are barely any examples available that I can look into. Any help would be appreciated

```
 compositeChart.width(1200)
             .height(240)
             .margins({top: 10, right: 100, bottom: 70, left:80})
             .transitionDuration(800)
         .dimension(depValue)
         .elasticY(true)
             .filter('(All)')
             .x(d3.scale.ordinal().domain(["AUTO & TIRES","BABY","CLOTHING","ELECTRONICS","GARDEN","GROCERY","HEALTH","HOME","HOME IMPROVEMENT", "PHOTO","SPORTS", "TOYS","VIDEO GAMES"]))
             .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
             .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
             .compose([
                    dc.barChart(compositeChart)
                            .width(1200)
                            .height(240)
                            .group(group,"This Year")
                            .valueAccessor(function (p) {return p.value})
                            .clickFilterBehavior("replace")
                            .title(function(d) { return d.key + ": " + d3.round(d.value,2); })
                            .barPadding(0.5)
                            .brushOn(false)
                            .elasticY(true)
                            .filter('(All)')
                            .margins({top: 10, right: 100, bottom: 70, left:80})
                            .gap(15),
                     dc.lineChart(compositeChart)
                            .width(1200)
                            .height(240)
                            .group(group1,"Last Year")
                            .valueAccessor(function (p) {return p.value})
                            .margins({top: 10, right: 100, bottom: 70, left:80})
                            .yAxisLabel($('metric').value+'(TY)')
                            .brushOn(false)
                            .title(function(d) { return d.key + ": " + d3.round(d.value,2); })
                            .elasticY(true)
                            .colors('black')
                  ])
                .yAxisLabel($('metric').value+'(TY)')
                .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
  compositeChart.renderlet(function(chart){
  chart.selectAll("g.x text")
    .attr('transform', "rotate(30)")
    .style('text-anchor','start')
    .style('font-weight','bold');
});
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am trying to fix a similar problem in my own code. Thanks!

Comment: I added the numbers for the linechart in the tool-tip of bar chart.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, but I managed to solve it in a weird way. On my chart I have a `resetAll` button and when pressed it would make the line tooltips functional. After a few tries, I found that calling `renderAll()` twice does the trick. I have no idea how that fixes it, but I think it might be a bug with `dc.js`.

```
dc.renderAll();
dc.renderAll();
```

Comment: Another solution is to call .render() on the composite chart itself and then call dc.renderAll() afterwards